# How to direct to a url and pass the JWT token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jwt, token

A React SPA `-X-` must redirect the user to a second React SPA `-Z-` where it provide certain query params so that the Z application can do its job.

The problem I'm facing is that I need to pass the `JWT token` from X to Z. Passing the token in the url is not an option for security reasons. How Can I do this, never faced a scenario like this.